# MPMoviePlayerController: Seek Button tap freezes video - black screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller, freeze

I am playing a video using `MPMoviePlayerController`. I am getting a black screen that does not respond to taps on controls in the following scenarios:

1. User taps on fast-forward button
2. User taps on rewind button
3. User long-holds, and fast-forwards to the end of the video

All the other controls work as expected.

Note that a long-hold on fast-forward and rewind *does* work as expected.

I did look at the documentation at the link below. There are notifications for when the user is seeking forward and backward (e.g., long holding); respectively, `MPMoviePlaybackStateSeekingForward` and `MPMoviePlaybackStateSeekingBackward`. That being said, there are no notifications for a simple_tap_ on the seek buttons.

Link is "[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006953-CH3-SW17)".

For completeness, here is the code that I'm using to call the player. Nothing really out of the ordinary; when video ends (observing `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification`), I rewind to the beginning.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"catSleeping" ofType:@mp4"];
_videoPlayer =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
                 initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
[_videoPlayer prepareToPlay];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                         name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:_videoPlayer];
_videoPlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;
_videoPlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
[self.view addSubview:_videoPlayer.view];
[_videoPlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
[_videoPlayer play];
}

- (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification {
    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [notification object];
    player.currentPlaybackTime = 0.1;
    [player stop];
    [player play];
    [player pause];
}
```

Any ideas?

tyvm
Keith :)

Answer (score 5):

When your fast-forward or rewind buttons are single tapped, the players load state is unknown. You need to handle the MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification and reload the path to the video and prepareToPlay again.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(playerLoadStateChanged:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification
                                           object:nil];

- (void)playerLoadStateChanged:(NSNotification *)notification {

    MPMovieLoadState loadState = _videoPlayer.loadState;

    if(loadState == MPMovieLoadStateUnknown) {
        _videoPlayer.contentURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.path]
        [_videoPlayer prepareToPlay];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> ... getting a black screen that does not respond to taps on controls in the following scenarios:
>
> 1. User taps on fast-forward button

- Single tap on `Fast-Forward` behaves as `Next`

---

> 2. User taps on rewind button

- Single tap on `Rewind` behaves as `Previous`

So... in both cases above, your player is no longer referring to the video you are expecting and has moved on.

---

> 3. User long-holds, and fast-forwards to the end of the video

- Long Press till end of video should not give you a black screen.
  *Check this scenario once again*.

---

I don't know if there's a way to modify the default behavior of the `MPMoviePlayerController` controls but if you want a single tap on fast-forward/rewind to go ahead/behind in the video by some X seconds, then you can create your own custom view with buttons and assign `MPMoviePlayerController`'s instance methods like:

- `-play` / `-stop`
- `-setCurrentPlaybackTime:`
- `-beginSeekingForward` / `-beginSeekingBackward`

---

I'd use the methods above and utilize an `NSTimer` for the fastfoward/rewind buttons and handle this timer on control events like `UIControlEventTouchDown` & `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` to determine whether to increment/decrement the `currentPlaybackTime` by X seconds or to `-beginSeekingForward` / `-beginSeekingBackward`.